# setTermInfosIndexDivisor problem in IndexReader with Lucene 3.0.2

Tags: lucene

I am upgrading lucene 2.4.1 to 3.0.2 in my java web project, in IndexReader
Lucene 2.4.1 has method setTermInfosIndexDivisor but
in Lucene 3.0.2 we have to set it on opening an IndexReader

my question is how we can set TermInfosIndexDivisor if i don't have indexDeletionPolicy??
because when opening an IndexReader if you want to set TermInfosIndexDivisor
then you also have to pass indexDeletionPolicy in Lucene 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

A guess, but passing null will make it default to a `KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy`. At least, that's how it works in 2.9.